# What does the expression (*T)(nil) mean

Tags: go

I came across these two statements in the testing package

```golang
var _ TB = (*T)(nil)
var _ TB = (*B)(nil)
```

Here's is a simple program to try and investigate what this evaluates to

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type TB interface{}
type T struct{}
var x TB = (*T)(nil)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T, %v", x, x)
}
```

output

```
*main.T, <nil>
```

Question is, what does this syntax mean and what is its use, specifically in this case where we assign to the blank identifier? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compile time check to ensure the types `*T` and `*B` satisfy the interface `TB`. So if you modify `*T` or `*B` that no longer satisfies `TB`, you will get a compile error.

It doesn't affect runtime at all. The blank identified tells the compiler it can throw it out.